# Is there any OWASP checking tool for scala project?

Tags: scala, owasp, owasp-dependency-check

I found there is an OWASP dependency checking tool for Java projects:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check

I tried the tool on Scala projects, but it can find no dependencies.

Is there any similar thing for Scala projects?

Comment: Which build tool are you using?

Answer (score 5):

There is one now (June 2016): [**`albuch/sbt-dependency-check`**](https://github.com/albuch/sbt-dependency-check) from [Alexander v. Buchholtz](https://github.com/albuch).

> SBT Plugin for OWASP DependencyCheck.
> This can be used to monitor dependencies used in an application and report if there are any publicly known vulnerabilities (e.g. CVEs).

> Runs dependency-check against the current project,its aggregate and dependencies and generates a report for each project.

You need to add to your project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("net.vonbuchholtz" % "sbt-dependency-check" % "3.3.0")
```

and after that simply call

```
$ sbt dependencyCheck
```

The report will be written to the location crossTarget.value(by default it is target/scala-2.11/).

Comment: As of today the current version is 3.3.0 - Don't blindly copy&paste the snippet above! Always check if there's a more recent version available.

Comment: @user1053510 Indeed. Could you edit this answer and put the updated snippet for SBT 3.3.0?